# achemso package in suppinfo mode does not show Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, achemso

I am writing a JACS communication Supporting Information in Latex using achemso package where the manuscript type set to suppinfo.

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=suppinfo]{achemso}
```

I am then calling for the contents (sections and subsections) with:

```
\tableofcontents
```

As here in the simplified form

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=suppinfo]{achemso}
\title{Title goes here}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Header 1}
\subsection{Header 1.1}
\subsection{Header 1.2}
\subsection{Header 1.3}
\subsection{Header 1.4}
\section{Header 3}
\section{Header 4}
\section{Header 5}
\section{Header 6}

\end{document}
```

But I get an empty contents section [image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: Do you compile your document twice? Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Yes I did multiple times but doesn't work.. Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately I'n not familiar with `achemso` document class. With `article` your MWE works as expected. Hopefully here are some users who will be able help you.

Comment: indeed it is something related to the achemso package. I also tried with simple article class and it works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard settings used unnumbered sections for `supinfo`: these are not written to the `.toc` file. You need to add

```
\SectionNumbersOn
```

before `\begin{document}` to reactivate them.

Comment: it worked like a charm! Thanks a lot Joseph!